# Why does my Git mergetool configuration not work?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config, meld, p4merge

I want to set `trustExitCode` to false and `keepTemporaries` to true but it does not work... I don't underestand why. Here is my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
        conflictstyle = diff3
        tool = p4merge
[mergetool]
        keepTemporaries = true
        keepBackup = true
        trustExitCode = false
[mergetool "p4merge"]
        trustExitCode = false
        keepTemporaries = true
[mergetool "mymeld"]
        cmd = meld --diff $BASE $LOCAL --diff $BASE $REMOTE --diff $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE
        trustExitCode = false
        keepTemporaries = true
[mergetool "myp4merge"]
        cmd = p4merge $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
        trustExitCode = false
        keepTemporaries = true
```

When I save some modification, either with p4merge, myp4merge or mymeld, Git doesn't ask me the expected "Was the merge successful? [y/n]" and does not leave file.BASE, file.REMOTE, ...

I can't find the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `path` setting to `mergetool XYZ` config instead of `cmd`. Here is my own setting that works properly.

```
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = PATH_TO_KDIFF3
    trustExitCode = false
    keepTemporaries = true
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = true
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
    conflictstyle = diff3
```