# Git: get $REMOTE, $BASE and $LOCAL files when fixing merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

When I have to fix merge conflict, I would like to ask git to give me the $REMOTE, $BASE and $LOCAL files (because the option `keepTemporaries` does not seem to work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245927/why-does-my-git-mergetool-configuration-not-work) thread). Is there any command to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From `git help gitrevisions`:

```
    :<n>:<path>, e.g. :0:README, :README
        A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the
        index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a
        merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch_s version (typically the current branch), and
        stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.
```

So, if you are in the middle of `git checkout mybranch; git merge otherbranch`, and you have a conflict on `conflict.txt`, then, `git show :2:conflict.txt` will show the version of the file from `mybranch` (your "$LOCAL"), `git show :3:conflict.txt` will show the version from otherbranch (your "$REMOTE"), and `git show :1:conflict.txt` will show the version from the commit identified by `git merge-base mybranch otherbranch` (your "$BASE").

For files that are not in conflict, use `git show :0:cleanfile.txt` or just `git show cleanfile.txt`.